# How to wait for a function to be invoked from a different location?

Tags: rust

I'm looking for a feature that lets you do something like that:

```
For msg in stream {
  match msg.id {
    0 -> //if "thing0()" is waiting, let it continue and return msg.value, it not, drop the msg and do nothing
    1 -> //same here for "thing1()"
    _ -> {}
  }
}

async fn getMessage0Value() {
  thing0().await
}
async fn getMessage1Value()  {
  thing1().await
}
```

Another solution that came to my mind was to listen to the stream in every "getMessageXValue" fn and filtering for the relevant `msg.id`s, but then the `msg`s that aren't filtered for wouldn't be dropped (I think).

Comment: Please provide a more comprehensive description of what you are trying to achieve. It's not quite clear to me with what your comments in the code mean. What is `stream`? What is the type of `msg`? Where does `getMessage0Value()` get called?  What is `thing0()`?

Comment: I start to understand what you are trying to achieve, although it is worded in a very confusing way. So you are getting messages, and if someone is expecting the message you want to send it to them, otherwise you want to ignore the message? What happens if multiple tasks are waiting inside `getMessage0Value()` simultaneously? Is `msg` `Clone`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have something like a `channel` that only sends messages when a receiver already exists.

I assume that when multiple receivers are registered, you only want to deliver the message to one of them, otherwise the message would have to implement `Clone`.

Further, I assume that you receivers to be processed in a first-come-first-serve order.

My idea to solve this is by having a `Vec` with potential receivers that are connected via a [`oneshot`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/oneshot/index.html) channel.

So this is what I came up with:

```
use std::{
    collections::VecDeque,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
    time::Duration,
};

use tokio::sync::oneshot;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct MessageDispatcher<Msg> {
    waiters: Arc<Mutex<VecDeque<oneshot::Sender<Msg>>>>,
}

impl<Msg> MessageDispatcher<Msg> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            waiters: Arc::new(Mutex::new(VecDeque::new())),
        }
    }

    fn dispatch(&self, mut msg: Msg) {
        loop {
            match self.waiters.lock().unwrap().pop_front() {
                Some(sender) => {
                    // If receiver available, try to send
                    match sender.send(msg) {
                        // Sent successfully
                        Ok(()) => break,
                        // Sending failed, move msg back to its variable and try again
                        Err(failed_msg) => msg = failed_msg,
                    }
                }
                // If no receiver available, do nothing
                None => break,
            }
        }
    }

    async fn receive(&self) -> Msg {
        let (sender, receiver) = oneshot::channel();
        self.waiters.lock().unwrap().push_back(sender);
        receiver.await.unwrap()
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let message_dispatcher: MessageDispatcher<String> = MessageDispatcher::new();

    // No waiter, nothing happens
    message_dispatcher.dispatch("Message1".to_string());

    // Attach receiver
    let message_receiver = message_dispatcher.clone();
    let joinhandle = tokio::spawn(async move {
        let msg = message_receiver.receive().await;
        println!("Received: {}", msg);
    });

    // Sleep for a while to make sure the receiver is actually attached
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;

    // Receiver should receive this message and print it
    message_dispatcher.dispatch("Message2".to_string());

    // Receiver exited after the last message, so this one should be ignored again
    message_dispatcher.dispatch("Message3".to_string());

    // Wait for the receiver task to close
    joinhandle.await.unwrap();
}
```

```
Received: Message2
```

Answer (score -1):

In theory you could use a zero size crossbeam channel with `try_send`:

```rust
use crossbeam_channel::bounded;

let (s0, r0) = bounded(0);
let (s1, r1) = bounded(0);

for msg in stream {
  match msg.id {
    // should fail immediately if there isn't a receiver active and so drop the message
    0 => s0.try_send(msg.value), 
    1 => s1.try_send(msg.value),
    _ => Ok({})
  }
}

async fn getMessage0Value() {
  // This might need wrapped as it is a blocking call to avoid locking up a thread.
  // e.g. tokio::task::spawn_blocking
  r0.recv();
}
async fn getMessage1Value()  {
  r1.recv();
}
```

https://docs.rs/crossbeam-channel/latest/crossbeam_channel/struct.Sender.html#method.try_send
https://docs.rs/crossbeam-channel/latest/crossbeam_channel/fn.bounded.html#examples

You might need to play around with the receive side to get it to work with async.

Unfortunately tokio channels don't support 0 buffer size.

> Panics if the buffer capacity is 0.

https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html

Comment: `Receiver::recv` is a *blocking call*. Never use blocking calls in `async` Rust, it will block the entire event loop.

Comment: You could wrap it in `tokio::task::spawn_blocking`, and if you add it to your code I will remove my comment, but until then this code is dangerous and will produce bugs that are hard to find if copy-pasted by someone.

Comment: The OP didn't mention tokio so I didn't want to assume the library. I have improved the comment to make it clearer that the `recv` is blocking.